# Best method for drawing a moving line JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I wish to have a line going across my canvas element in a similar fashion to the one I have managed to produce below after I had read up a little about the tween function:

http://jsfiddle.net/MjLdT/17/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var line = new Kinetic.Line({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    points: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    stroke: '#000000'
});

layer.add(line);
stage.add(layer);

var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: line,
    duration: 3,
    x: 800,
    y: 100,
    points: [-700, 0, 800, 0]
});


setTimeout(function () {
    tween.play();
}, 2000);
```

Eventually I wish to have users be able to manipulate the line by clicking the left mouse button and the line goes up and to the right diagonally, right clicking and the line goes down diagonally (horizontal speed towards the right of the screen remains the same). Letting go of the mouse button will result in it returning to it's normal horizontal motion at whatever 'height' it is on the screen at that time.

This is one of my first attempts at using JavaScript and was wondering if the method I have chosen is appropriate for what I wish to achieve.

Also, any tips on how to get started on the mouse effects would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The method is appropriate and it works, you should look into Kinetic.Animation which may give you slightly cleaner code.  With an animation you can put more logic into the code that is being re-run.  I believe tweens may be limited for what you are trying to do, it is possible but Animations are probably what you are looking for if you are aiming for a good design.

I would read through this documentation. 
http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Animation.html